# JS Prototype screwing around with me

Tags: javascript, prototypejs

```
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen" href="style.css"/>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="prototype.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $('lol').update('Hi!');
    </script>

    <title>Memory Game</title>
</head>
<body>
    <h1 id="lol">Hello</h1>

</body>
```

---

Simple enough.
Nothing happens and this is what FF gives me in the console:

$("lol") is null
[Break On Errors] $('lol').update('Hi!');
index.html (row 10)

What am I missing?

Answer (score 2):

Scripts run immediately as the script element is parsed. Since the script element appears before `lol`, it can't find it.

Either move the script to the end of the document, or delay execution someone (e.g. by wrapping it in a function and attaching that to the onload event).

Answer (score 1):

I think you should add a `#` if you are accessing by id:

```
$('#lol').update('Hi!');
```

EDIT: Sorry, I thought you were using jQuery. You need to put the

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $('lol').update('Hi!');
</script>
```

At the bottom of the page.

Comment: With the Prototype library, "$()" is a shortcut for "document.getElementById()".

Comment: Not for Prototype. You would add a # if you did $$('#lol').update('Hi!');

Answer (score 0):

```
window.load = function() { $('lol').update('Hi!'); })
```

Comment: It's Prototype.js, not jQuery.

Answer (score 0):

Try the cross-browser compatible on DOM load method, this fires when the document is loaded but before the page is drawn:

```
<script>
document.observe("dom:loaded", function() {
  $('lol').update('Hi!');
});
</script>
```

You can also put simple script tags rather than text/whateverscript.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe your missing a document ready check:

```
document.observe("dom:loaded", function() {
  $('lol').update('Hi!');
});
```

jsFiddle example here: http://jsfiddle.net/qWzTp/1/